# I think I'm stuck on an island. How can I escape it?

Tags: dont-starve

I am stuck on an island. I have looked all over it, and there is only one wormhole, which leads to another island on the complete opposite side of the map.

I am running out of resources. Is there anything I can do to reach the rest of the map?

Comment: Are you in Adventure Mode, by any chance?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are 'stuck' on an island, but you found a wormhole to escape the island? Well... how about you use the wormhole?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to take the wormhole to this other place on the map and go from there. There's no "sequential order" to visiting the entire map. No biggie!

Answer (score 1):

If anything, you should try exploring the island on the other side of the wormhole, which could have more resources. There might be other wormholes to other places, with more resources.